# If a topological space is an element of another topological space, is it also a subset of a topological space?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

So I've been attempting to solve a problem surrounding topological spaces. The question states:
Suppose $d_1$, $d_2$ are metrics on a non-empty set $X$ such that $B_{d_2}(x,r) \in \tau (X, d_1) \text{ for any } x \in X, \text{ any } r > 0$. Show that $\tau (X, d_2) \subset \tau(X, d_1)$.

So far, this is how I went:

$$
(X, d_2) := \cup {x \in X: \exists r > 0: B_{d_2} (x,r) \in X}
$$
This is a m.s. as it inherits the properties of $\tau (X, d_1)$.
Since all metric spaces are topological spaces, we have $\tau (X, d_2)$

This gives us:
$$
\tau (X, d_2) \in \tau(X,d_1)
$$
But I'm unsure whether this implies that $\tau (X, d_2) \in \tau(X,d_1)$. Can I show that since the topological space consists of multiple elements, it will be a subset rather than an element of the topological space?

Comment: This is just asking you to show that every $d_2$-open set is also $d_1$-open.  Just use the definition of open-ness.

Comment: @Randall , I'm a bit confused. GIven that I know that the ball centred at $x$ in $d_2$ is an element of the union of all open sets which are unions of all open balls centred at any $x$ with some radius $\epsilon$ on $d_1$, do I just need to prove that if I take the same point $x$ for both balls, I need to show that the ball in $d_2$ is inside the ball in $d_1$?

Comment: No, you don't need that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U$ be any $d_2$-open set (so, a member of $\tau(X,d_2)$).  This means--since an open set is made up entirely of interior points--that
$$
U = \bigcup_{x \in U} B_{d_2}(x,r_x)
$$
for some radii $r_x >0$.  But by assumption each $B_{d_2}(x,r_x)$ is open in $\tau(X,d_1)$, so $U$ is a union of open sets in $\tau(X,d_1)$, so $U$ is also open in $\tau(X,d_1)$. Done.